# where to keep the AES keystream?

Tags: aes

I am trying to implement an AES encryption on my messages in my app and I want to have a different keystream for each "message group". Therefore, currently I am holding the keystreams in the database of the message groups. And the messages get decrypted by the app. However, there is one problem. The app is talking to the server via REST, and I need to get the encryption keys in a secure way. I am thinking of another keystream to encrypt the keystreams of message groups but I don't know where to keep it. Should I keep it in the app?

Comment: Your concept does not sound like a good idea from a security standpoint

Comment: Are you sure you mean [keystream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystream)?

Comment: maybe I am getting the terminology wrong; what I mean is the text to encrypt the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never keep keystreams. You should keep a key, and store an IV or Nonce with the ciphertext. You *first* need to think about where to store the key, if you store it in the same location or with the same security as your ciphertext, your scheme is meaningless.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098183/c-sharp-cryptography-aes-key-generate/25098390#25098390) I just created on Stackoverflow, and learn about *key management*. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption) on the Information Security site also seems very on topic for you.

Comment: I am going to check this one out. The PGP system sounds very promising.

Comment: For a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) that uses a hierarchical model (often more useful for servers, you know, with CA & root certificates) check out CMS instead of PGP, which uses a *web of trust*.

Comment: I have googled a lot and found a free cryptography book. Currently reading it, getting familiar with the concepts, terminology, and techniques. Cryptography has always been an area of interest of mine, so I guess now its time to use it :)